# Unexpected segmentation fault while using double pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, double-pointer

I'm learning C. I'm messing around with pointers to understand how they work, but I can't really understand why I'm getting the errors that I explain ahead.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAT_COLS 13
#define MAT_ROWS 12

void test(char **, size_t, size_t);

int main(void)
{
    char *matrix[MAT_ROWS] = {"############", "############", "############", "############", "############", "############", "############", "############", "############", "############", "############", "############"};
    test(matrix, MAT_ROWS, MAT_COLS);
}

void test(char **Mat, size_t mat_rows, size_t mat_cols)
{
    printf("\n%s", Mat[3]);
    printf("\n%c", Mat[3][5]);
    printf("\n%s", (Mat + 3)); //strange output
    printf("\n%c", *(*(Mat + 3) + 5));
    fflush(stdout);
    Mat[3][5] = 46; //seg. fault
}
```

The output is:

```
############
#
`UUUU
#
```

I got two unexpected behavior:

- The strange output of the line `printf("\n%s", (Mat + 3));`: `UUUU
- The last line of the function test `Mat[3][5] = 46;` give me segmentation fault.

I used the debugger and `Mat+3` is the address of a string of matrix, but it outputs that strange string.

What is the problem?

Comment: You have an array of pointers, each pointer is initialized to point to a string literal. String literals may *not* be modified, and any attempt to do so will lead to *undefined behavior*. Literal strings are essentially *read-only*.

Comment: And `(Mat + 3)` is the same as `&Mat[3]`, which have the type `char **`. It doesn't point to a valid null-terminated string.

Comment: To add to that, make sure you enable compiler warnings, or even turn them into errors so you cannot ignore them (`-Wall -Werror` for GCC and Clang), as the compiler should have notified you that this is unsafe.